# Propositional Logic: Proof involving only the symbols $\{\rightarrow,F \}$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I feel like I literally tried everything. I'm exhausted, and could really use some help.
I was instructed to prove some logic proposition using only the symbols $\{\rightarrow,F \}$.
Let me first describe the proof system I'm using.
It is quite long, so please bare with me, or skip ahead if the staff looks familiar to you.

---

The propositional proof system is the following:

The axioms (schemes) are:
$A_1: \hspace{10pt}(\varphi\rightarrow(\psi\rightarrow\varphi))$
$A_2: \hspace{10pt}((\varphi\rightarrow(\psi\rightarrow\eta))\rightarrow((\varphi\rightarrow\psi)\rightarrow(\varphi\rightarrow\eta)))$
$A_3: \hspace{10pt}(((\varphi\rightarrow F)\rightarrow F)\rightarrow\varphi)$

(I think they called Lyndon Axioms...)

The inference rule is Modus Ponens, namely; given:
$\varphi\rightarrow\psi$
$\varphi$
We can conclude $\psi$.

---

As a quick example, given $\Sigma=\{F\}$ let me show how I'll prove $P$. Meaning, I'll show $\Sigma \vdash P$:

(1) $F$ (assumption)
(2) $(F\rightarrow ((P\rightarrow F)\rightarrow F))$  (instantiating $A_1$ with $\varphi=F$ and $\psi=(P\rightarrow F)$)
(3) $((P\rightarrow F)\rightarrow F)$ (Modus Ponens of (1) and (2))
(4) $(((P\rightarrow F)\rightarrow F)\rightarrow P)$  (instantiating $A_3$ with $\varphi=P$)
(5) $P$ (Modus Ponens of (3) and (4))

---

Now, since even trivial proofs can be insanely long and tedious, I am allowed to use the following four rules:

### 1. The Deduction Rule:

$\Sigma\vdash \varphi\rightarrow \psi\iff\Sigma\cup\{\varphi\}\vdash\psi$

This rule can make life much easier.
For example, using this rule, this: $\Sigma=\{A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C)\}\vdash B\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C)$ can be proven real quick.

### 2. Transitive Rule:

$\{\varphi\rightarrow\psi, \psi\rightarrow \eta\}\vdash \varphi\rightarrow\eta$

Not much to say, quite an intuitive rule.

### 3. Contra-Positive Rule:

$\{\varphi\rightarrow\psi\}\vdash (\psi\rightarrow F)\rightarrow (\varphi\rightarrow F)$

Also a well known rule.

### 4. Proof by Cases:

If $\Sigma\cup\{\varphi\}\vdash \psi$ and $\Sigma\cup\{\varphi\rightarrow F\}\vdash \psi$ then $\Sigma\vdash \psi$

This is also intuitive, if you think about it...
My way of understanding it is: If you can prove something with $\varphi$ and you can also prove it with $\neg \varphi$, then it must be that you can prove it regardless of what $\varphi$ is. In some sense, it does not contribute anything.

---

Now, going back to my problem, this is what I need to prove:
Consider $\Sigma$:
$\Sigma=\{$
(1) $(D\wedge \neg Y)\rightarrow H$
(2) $H\rightarrow (H\wedge D)\vee(H\wedge Y)$
(3) $\neg (D\wedge H)$
(4) $D\vee H\vee Y$
$\}$

I need to prove $\Sigma\vdash Y$.

So first, I translated it to propositions over $\{\rightarrow,F\}$:

(1) $(((D\rightarrow Y)\rightarrow F)\rightarrow H)$
(2) $(H\rightarrow((H\rightarrow(D\rightarrow F))\rightarrow ((H\rightarrow(D\rightarrow Y))\rightarrow F)))$
(3) $(D\rightarrow (H\rightarrow F))$
(4) $((((D\rightarrow F)\rightarrow H)\rightarrow F)\rightarrow Y)$

Obviously, there are plenty of ways to translate this propositions, and I'm wondering if it'll be easier to prove with some other translation.

From this group of four propositions, I need to prove $Y$.
I really tried a lot of ways to attack this problem, but it seems that no matter what I try, I keep getting back to the same point - meaning inferring staff I already have as assumptions.

For example, I tried to use "Proof By Cases"; to prove that $\Sigma\cup \{H\}\vdash Y$ and also that $\Sigma\cup \{H\rightarrow F\}\vdash Y$, but this led me nowhere.
I tried to use the axioms: arbitrarily instantiating schemes to see if I can infer anything new, but this quickly became exhausting, as the propositions grew very long, very fast.
I tried to find how can the Induction Rule be used, but couldn't.
I even tried to prove this using the original $\Sigma$, and then work my way back to the $\{\rightarrow,F\}$ symbols, with no luck.
Is this really a non-trivial task, or am I missing something here?

I will very appreciate any comment, thanks for reading through this long post.

Comment: I would save the reduction to $\to$ until later, as that sort of stuff can be managed later on. It might help to draw a table of the 16 possible entries of $D,H,Y$ and show how $\Sigma$ leaves only rows with $Y=1$ that can be true. In particular, use (4),(3), (1), (2). I haven't solved the problem as above, but with a truth table, only rows with $Y=1$ remain. Perhaps you can see if this helps guide the proof using the above rules?

Comment: Hi @copper.hat. 
Unfortunately, I must provide a syntactic proof, with no use of propositions semantic. This rules-out the use of truth table, or any inference from truth assignments...

Comment: I don't understand something in your example: Apparently, starting from the assumption of any arbitrary proposition $F$ you have proven some arbitrary other proposition $P$.  That would make this inference system singularly uninteresting.  What have I missed there?

Comment: $F$ is $\perp$.

Comment: The purported translations of (1), (2), and (4) don't seem right.  For example, the translation of (2) seems to say $H\to (H\wedge D)\vee (H\wedge D\wedge \neg Y)$ instead.

Comment: If there's a way to show that (a)$(D\wedge \neg Y)\rightarrow H \vdash \neg D\vee Y \vee H$, (b)$H\rightarrow (H\wedge D)\vee(H\wedge Y) \vdash \neg H\vee (H\wedge D)\vee(H\wedge Y)$, (c)$\neg H\vee (H\wedge D)\vee(H\wedge Y) , \neg (D\wedge H) \vdash \neg H\vee(H\wedge Y)$ , (d)$\neg D\vee Y \vee H\vdash, D\vee H\vee Y \vdash H\vee Y$, (f)$\neg H\vee(H\wedge Y) \vdash H\rightarrow Y$, (g)$H\vee Y, H\rightarrow Y\vdash Y$ , you've done.

Comment: @Steven: I’ve not checked (2), but (1) and (4) are right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : Hm, my mistake.  I thought they looked like misparenthesizations of what I considered the obvious translations, and didn't look further.  My bad.

Comment: "I think they called Lyndon Axioms.."

On p. 218 of J. A. Kalman's *Automated Reasoning With Otter* he indicates that these three axioms appear in a 1939 paper of Wajsberg (the axioms are in Polish notation, but this is not material here).

Comment: "D∨H∨Y" From your translation it's clear that you meant ((D∨H)∨Y).  You didn't make this clear until you did the translation.

Comment: The OR operator $\vee$ is associative, so I omitted the parentheses. I also mentioned that you can translate it in many ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest proving $\Sigma\vdash D\to Y$ and $\Sigma\vdash H\to Y$ (and $\Sigma\vdash Y\to Y$), then using (4).

Here's a proof of $\Sigma\vdash D\to Y$, first in a "friendly" form, then the (fairly mechanical) translation to a form using just the tools you've listed.

*Friendly form:*  Suppose $D$.  Suppose further that not $Y$.  By (1), $H$ would follow.  But then $D$ and $H$ are both true, contrary to (3).  Therefore our assumption that not $Y$ is false, so $Y$ is true.  We supposed $D$ and proved $Y$; therefore $D\to Y$.

*Using just available tools:* First I show that $\Sigma\cup\{D,Y\to F\}\vdash F$.
\begin{align*}
&\text{a.} && D &&\text{assumption} \\
&\text{b.} && D\to(Y\to F)\to H &&\text{alternative translation of (1)} \\
&\text{c.} && (Y\to F)\to H &&\text{modus ponens, b & a} \\
&\text{d.} && Y\to F &&\text{assumption} \\
&\text{e.} && H &&\text{modus ponens, c & d} \\
&\text{f.} && D\to (H\to F) &&\text{your translation of (3)} \\
&\text{g.} && H\to F &&\text{modus ponens, f & a}\\
&\text{h.} && F &&\text{modus ponens, g & e}
\end{align*}

Now we proceed:

\begin{align*}
&\text{p.} & \Sigma\cup\{D,Y\to F\} &\vdash F && \text{proof above} \\
&\text{q.} & \Sigma\cup\{D\} &\vdash (Y\to F)\to F && \text{deduction theorem} \\
&\text{r.} & \Sigma\cup\{D\} &\vdash Y && \text{$A_3$ & modus ponens} \\
&\text{s.} & \Sigma &\vdash D\to Y && \text{deduction theorem}
\end{align*}

Comment: Beautiful answer, thanks! Couple of questions though. Why am I allowed to prove $\Sigma\vdash D\rightarrow Y$ instead (of $\Sigma \vdash Y$)? It looks like a use in the Deductive Rule, but(!) $D$ is neither in my assumptions, nor can I infer it from them. 
Second question: When I assume $Y\rightarrow F$ and proves $F$, to what rule does this trick fall to?  
Thanks again, Steven, this is very helpful.

Comment: Re proving $D\to Y$ instead of $Y$: It's more that $D\to Y$ is one step towards proving $Y$, as suggested in the first paragraph.  The idea is that if $D\to Y$ and $H\to Y$ (and $Y\to Y$), then $D\vee H\vee Y\to Y$.  How to render that reasoning within the allowed rules, I leave to you.  (It'll depend in part on your choice of translation of (4).)

Comment: Re assuming $Y\to F$ and deducing $F$: I'm not sure what you're asking.  There's no rule there; I just put $Y\to F$ in my context to the left of $\vdash$ and then referred to it, the same way you used $F$ in your proof that $\{F\}\vdash P$.  I guess the deduction rule does come in later on, at "q"; is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you!

Comment: OK, I found a much faster way to prove it, I wonder if it is appropriate to post it...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I'll add my full answer, then. For other who might be interested...

Answer (score 1):

My problem was insisting on the above translation. Although I was aware that other translations are also possible, I didn't think it will have such a dramatic effect on the proof stages. This was important since, as I mentioned above, even a seemingly trivial proof - using only the axioms - can be painful.
Another problem I had is that it didn't occur to me that there is no restriction on how many time to use the Proof by Cases in my proof, and as I will demonstrate below, that was the key.

---

An alternative translation to $\Sigma$ can be:
\begin{align*}
&(1) &&D\rightarrow ((H\rightarrow F)\rightarrow Y)\\
&(2) &&(D\rightarrow F)\rightarrow (H\rightarrow Y)\\
&(3) &&D\rightarrow (H\rightarrow F)\\
&(4) &&(D\rightarrow F)\rightarrow ((H\rightarrow F)\rightarrow Y)
\end{align*}

Using proof by cases, I'll show $\Sigma\cup\{D\}\vdash Y$ and $\Sigma\cup\{D\rightarrow F\}\vdash Y$:

*Case 1:* $\Sigma\cup\{D\}\vdash Y$
\begin{align*}
&(5) && D &&  \text{assumption} \\
&(6) && H\rightarrow F &&  \text{MP of (3) and (5)} \\
&(7) && (H\rightarrow F)\rightarrow Y &&  \text{MP of (1) and (5)} \\
&(8) && Y &&  \text{MP of (6) and (7)} \\
\end{align*}

*Case 2:* $\Sigma\cup\{D\rightarrow F\}\vdash Y$
Again, using Proof By Cases, we split the case to two cases.
Denote $\Sigma\,'=\Sigma\cup \{D\rightarrow F\}$, I'll show $\Sigma\,'\cup\{H\}\vdash Y$ and $\Sigma\,'\cup\{H\rightarrow F\}\vdash Y$.

*Case 2.1:* $\Sigma\,'\cup\{H\}\vdash Y$
\begin{align*}
&(6) && H &&  \text{assumption} \\
&(7) && H\rightarrow Y &&  \text{MP of (2) and (5)} \\
&(8) && Y &&  \text{MP of (6) and (7)} \\
\end{align*}

*Case 2.2:* $\Sigma\,'\cup\{H\rightarrow F\}\vdash Y$
\begin{align*}
&(6) && H\rightarrow F &&  \text{assumption} \\
&(7) && (H\rightarrow F)\rightarrow Y &&  \text{MP of (4) and (5)} \\
&(8) && Y &&  \text{MP of (6) and (7)} \\
\end{align*}

Thus I conclude $\Sigma\vdash Y$.